# how to change the text of the texview in android

Tags: android, button, textview

Hi i am making simple quote application which display quotes.
I have the quotes in sqlite database. I have two button "next" and "previous"
when user hit next the next quote should display and and when hit previous the previous quotes should display.Database is working fine but i am stuck at how to change the text of textView.I tried some things but they are not working properly.
Any suggestion or help?
quotes like jokes,proverbs etc.

Comment: ur question is not clear ... which quote u r talking abt give any example what u want to display,thn ppl can help u out...

Comment: problem solved from http://androidlearningbegin.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-application-to-connect-to-your.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m tring this it is working but when i click  next the previous text does not disappear.what to do?

```
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
 next.setOnClickListener(this);
 back.setOnClickListener(this);

    try {
        db=new DbH(this);
    } catch (IOException e2) {

        e2.printStackTrace();
    }


        try {
            db.createdatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    db.opendatabase();
     cur=db.data();
     cur.moveToFirst();


 //int i=0;

    tv.append(cur.getString(1));

 cur.moveToNext();
```

//  cur.close();

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

```
switch(R.id.next)
{
case R.id.next :
    cur.moveToNext();
    tv.append(""+cur.getString(1));
break;
case R.id.back:
{
    cur.moveToPrevious();
    tv.append(""+cur.getString(1));
    break;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly fetch all the quotes and store into the Arraylist or any equivalent object now use one counter object which will track the current position and initialize it with 0 if you get the quote more than equals to 1

now on the next button check first counter value is equals to the arraylist size then do nothing otherwise increase by 1 and get the next quote from the arraylist

```
if(counter==-1)
    return;

if(counter==array.size()-1)
   return

counter++;
yourtextview.setText(array.get(counter));
```

do the same things into the previous, in this counter-- instead of counter++

Edit
without arraylist object and counter object

check the cursor using moveNext() and movePrevious() like for next check

```
   if(cursor.moveNext())
       yourtextview.setText(coursor.getString(yourcolumnindex));
```

and in previous

```
   if(cursor.movePrevious())
       yourtextview.setText(coursor.getString(yourcolumnindex));
```

Comment: is it right to load all the database in arraylist.i rather want to do that with the help of queries.

Comment: it is better to execute multiple query or you can do I think that fetch all the data and use the cursor object itself instead of arraylist object

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Use onClickListeners on your buttons. When the user presses the button you fetch the appropriate text from the database and display it for example by using [setText(CharSequence text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: while(cur.isAfterLast()==false)
    {  
     tv.append("\t\t"+getString(2));
     onClick(back);
     onClick(next);
    }
    cur.close(); is this correct? i implemented c.moveToNext and c.moveToPrevious in onClick method.

Comment: tv.setText("\t\t"+getString(2)); Would do. Or do you want to keep the old ones? Then append should do. Look at the docs: 
public final void append (CharSequence text)

Since: API Level 1
Convenience method: Append the specified text to the TextView's display buffer, upgrading it to BufferType.EDITABLE if it was not already editable.

Answer (score 0):

To change the text of textview:

```
textview.setText("your text");
```

if you are getting any exception in changing the text then try to do it with the help of `handler`.